# What happen if you don't call parent constructor explicitly in PHP?

Tags: php

I was wondering why we have to explicitly call parent constructor in PHP? What happen if, let's say, we forget to call the parent constructor in the derived class?

I thought that the derived class won't have access to the member properties or method of its parent class but after I try not to call parent constructor, it seems that the child class still get access to its parent public/protected member.

So do we have to explicitly call its parent constructor? What are the consequences if we forget to do so?

Thanks in advance. Any kinds of help will be appreciated :)

Comment: review your manual http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on your code. In it's simpliest nothing happens if you dont call parent constructor, but if your parent constructor does something initializing for parent class, all that is left out. Consider, and play with this:

```
<?php

class X {
    private $_a;

    public function __construct($a) {
        echo 'X::construct ';
        $this->_a = $a;
    }

    public function getA() {
        return $this->_a;
    }
}

class Y extends X {
    private $_b;

    public function __construct($a,$b) {
        echo 'Y::construct ';
        parent::__construct($a);
        $this->_b = $b;
    }

    public function getAB() {
        return $this->_b + $this->getA();
    }
}

$n = new Y(3,2);
echo $n->getAB();
```

It's easy to see that if you run this, it prints out 5 (among other dump). But if you comment `class Y` parent call `parent::__construct($a);`, you get 2. That is the consequence in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Because parent constructors are not called implicitly if the child class defines a constructor. If the child class assumes that the parent has initialized and done some work, it needs to ensure that the parent constructor is entered.

You might, for instance extend a class where you don't *want* the parent constructor to be entered. The behavior just allows for more flexibility in design. In most cases, you *probably* want to call the parent constructor.

It all depends on *why* you extended the parent. Do you need methods that require the parent to initialize? If yes, call its constructor. Can you just inject certain specific dependencies needed after extending it, or need simple things like constants? Then you probably don't need to.

Answer (score 1):

The consequences really depend on what happens in the parent constructor. All public and protected member properties and methods are available even when the parent constructor is not called, that is correct. But the values of inherited class members might be modified/initialized in the parent constructor - you will need to decide whether or not you want that to happen.

Its normally a good decision to always add a call to the parent constructor, even if nothing happens there (that might change in the future). The only reason to omit this call is when you need to override the actions that are taken in the constructor. That's a feature that adds more flexibility than you have e.g. in Java, where invoking the parent constructor is mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

The php manual explains it in very simple terms

> Note: Parent constructors are not called implicitly if the child class
> defines a constructor. In order to run a parent constructor, a call to
> `parent::__construct()` within the child constructor is required. If the
> child does not define a constructor then it may be inherited from the
> parent class just like a normal class method (if it was not declared
> as private).

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php